# setting up different asset route for a sub-folder in vendor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline, assets

Here is my folder structure:

[image]

In my `application.rb` I have:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/vendor/assets/bootstrap/css"
```

Which in theory should extend assets path with the new directory. In `application.css` I call:

```
*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/bootstrap/css.
```

then I get following error:

```
/vendor/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css isn't in paths: ...........
```

I have tried many different combinations right now, and I really don't know what is wrong.

Comment: it is, whats wrong with it? if i remove it, it doesnt make any difference

Comment: wow.... i had to restart server to make this work. i probably had some cache somewhere